# Generating a PWM frequency greater than 125 kHz using Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

I need to obtain a PWM frequency of at least 125 kHz. I plan to drive a pair of MOSFETs using this PWM as the driver signal. The below code gives a 1 kHz frequency. Can I just change the delay values to obtain a lower time period, and thereby a higher frequency?

```C++
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(100); // Approximately 10% duty cycle @ 1KHz
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);  // Can I change the delay to 1 and 9 for a totaL T=10 µsec and hence f = 100 kHz?
  delayMicroseconds(900);
}
```

---

**Update**

On looking up the answers provided, I stumbled across a few tutorials. I used the code below and it resulted in 125 kHz and 1.6 MHz (measured with a CRO, not simulation). But the code was supposed to provide 250 kHz and 8 MHz.

My requirement of 125 kHz is satisfied, but I am just curious to know why the [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) not working as it should.

Second sketch:

```C++
// A sketch that creates an 8 MHz, 50% duty cycle PWM and a 250 kHz,
// 6-bit resolution PWM with varying duty cycle (changes every 5µs
// or about every period.

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // Output pin for OCR2B
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); // Output pin for OCR0B

  // Set up the 250 kHz output (but cro measures only 125 kHz)
   TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
   TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20);
   OCR2A = 63;
   OCR2B = 0;

  // Set up the 8 MHz output
   TCCR0A = _BV(COM0A1) | _BV(COM0B1) | _BV(WGM01) | _BV(WGM00);
   TCCR0B = _BV(WGM02) | _BV(CS00);
   OCR0A = 1;
   OCR0B = 0;


  // Make the 250 kHz rolling
  while (1) {
    _delay_us(5);
    if (OCR2B < 63)
      OCR2B += 5;
    else
      OCR2B = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: The rolling part made it difficult to see on my scope, getting rid of that and setting OCR2B to 30 I seem to get a 250Khz waveform. Strange.

Comment: I made it and it works, what i noticed is that there is no 0 % duty cicle available. How can i make 0 % duty cicle?

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit beyond the normal Arduino capabilites so you need to delve into setting some of the registers for your ATMEGA chip directly. See the "Using the ATmega PWM registers directly" http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM

Comment: I fully agree with your advice, but I would consider this kind of timer programming perfectly within the "normal Arduino capabilities".

Comment: microtherion, what I meant was it's outside the "Arduino language" set of functions that will work across many varients of AVR (such as delay, digitalWrite etc.) and instead delving into registers that will likely be specific to a given AVR chip.

Answer (score 2):

> My requirement of 125 kHz is satisfied, but I am just curious to know why the sketch not working as it should.

According to my measurements, it is. Using this slightly modified version of your code:

```C++
// A sketch that creates an 8 MHz, 50% duty cycle PWM and a 250 kHz,
// 6-bit resolution PWM with varying duty cycle (changes every 5 µs
// or about every period.

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // Output pin for OCR2B
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); // Output pin for OCR0B

  // Set up the 250 kHz output
  TCCR2A = bit(COM2A1) | bit(COM2B1) | bit(WGM21) | bit(WGM20);
  TCCR2B = bit(WGM22) | bit(CS20);
  OCR2A = 63;
  OCR2B = 31;

  // Set up the 8 MHz output
  TCCR0A = bit(COM0A1) | bit(COM0B1) | bit(WGM01) | bit(WGM00);
  TCCR0B = bit(WGM02) | bit(CS00);
  OCR0A = 1;
  OCR0B = 0;
}
```

I get the predicted 8 MHz output on pin 5:

[image: 8 MHz scope output]

And the 250 kHz output on pin 3:

[image: 250 kHz scope output]

Answer (score 2):

To your original question: You can reduce the delay, but there's a limit to how small the delay can be.

Two reasons: Firstly, the loop() function does have some overhead, and secondly the code that you write takes time to execute. This is why the hardware PWM timer is valuable - it generates the pulses without much software intervention.

> I used the code below and it resulted in 125 kHz and 1.6 MHz (measured with a CRO, not simulation).

This is really just to add to Nick's answer...
(To understand what's going on, you need to refer to the datasheet. Based on your questions, I'm assuming you haven't stared at it long enough.)

#### In the first case: 125 kHz.

I am not sure if you're aware, but you're using a special mode of "Fast PWM" which is slightly different from the analogWrite() provided in Arduino.

In this mode, your PWM period is determined by the time it takes your timer counter to match the value in OCR2A register. This means that with a 16 MHz clock, and your output is toggled at a rate of 16 MHz/63 = 250 kHz (roughly).

So far so good, but what does the CRO see? The CRO considers a period to be made up of both high and low signal. It takes TWO 250 kHz cycles to toggle the signal up and down. Hence, the reading shows 125 kHz.

As to why the rolling would make your reading difficult: Think what kind of wave will appear when OCR0B = 0. ;-)

#### Case 2: 8 MHz

The same applies in the seccond case, and you should expect a 16 MHz cycle that toggles the signal up and down (which gives a 8 MHz reading on the CRO). As to why you are getting 1.6 MHz - that's an odd case. Can you post your CRO reading?

Comment: `The CRO considers a period to be made up of both high and low signal.` - indeed. The original code had such a short pulse that a scope might have interpreted each pulse as half a period, and thus halved the reported frequency. It might have missed the very short on cycle, which is why I adjusted the duty cycle up to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reduce the delay.

From the documentation:

> This function works very accurately in the range 3 microseconds and up. We cannot assure that `delayMicroseconds` will perform precisely for smaller delay-times.

Note that, there are a few cycles between the delays, so as you get shorter timeperiods, you will get less and less accuracy.

You could hand-code the delay. I would imagine you could get up to 1 MHz, but with little control over the duty cycle (at that frequency).You would need to disable interrupts, and you could do nothing else at all.

If you want still more, you could set a fuse on the ATmega, and get your native clock speed out on of pin 14 CKO (this shows up as digital pin 8 on the Arduino board) - I would expect a 50% duty cycle; you will have NO control over - you can't switch it on or off, or affect the duty cycle. It can be used to run multiple chips off the same clock.